# Hyperledger Fabric 2.0-beta Javascript Dev Mode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm running and adapting [chaincode dev mode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/chaincode-docker-devmode), for javascript chaincode, and for Fabric 2.0-beta. I launch the network and adapt the script.sh (client) to run:

```
set -e
peer channel create -c myc -f myc.tx -o orderer:7050
peer channel join -b myc.block

cd chaincode

peer lifecycle chaincode package chaincode.tar.gz --lang node --path ./ --label justicechain_1
peer lifecycle chaincode install chaincode.tar.gz
```

Nonetheless, I find the following error:

Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "+ INPUT_DIR=/chaincode/input
+ OUTPUT_DIR=/chaincode/output
+ cp -R /chaincode/input/src/. /chaincode/output
cp: can't stat '/chaincode/input/src/.': No such file or directory
"
/opt/gopath/src/chaincodedev/chaincode #

I couldn't find anything online regarding this issue. Any ideas?

EDIT: looks like there are updates - https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-18074

Comment: Did you actually start the peer in devmode? Its still trying to build the Chaincode, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: In the docker.yaml, the devmode environment variable is defined as true, so I supose yes. The chaincode doesn't need to be built, because its node js and not go chaincode

Comment: Let me test it. In 2.0 we added a new way of launching Chaincode, I'm not sure off the top of my head what our test coverage is for DevMode so I need to confirm it works

Comment: Appreciate it, @lindluni

Comment: Any resolution on this issue? I am getting the exact same error.

Comment: @lindluni any updates?

Comment: @lindluni any Updates ? I'm also facing this issue.

Comment: @AdarshaJha We only recently prioritized this. But we do have a developer working on it as of late last week. You can track it in our Jira here: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17584

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this question in offical document of Hyperledger Fabric and did not find a effient way to deal it